# Yii2 login. Yii::$app->user->login($user, 0) doesnt save

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2

I am trying implement login at my site. But seems like `Yii::$app->user->login($user, 0)` doesn't save identity.

When I've just logged in it work fine:

```
    if (Yii::$app->user->login($user, 0) ) {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity);
    } else {
        echo 'didnt login';
    }
```

`var_dump()` show identity.

But when I am trying obtain identity in another controller `var_dump()` shows `NULL`:

```
// In other controller
var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity);
```

Does somebody know about this problem?

Comment: Answer Following First : 1. (vendor directory) composer updated?. 2. Did your code for login matches with the site template? They keep changing the code yii2 is still not in stable format. 3. Did you made any modification to the login code.

Comment: yep, we're going to need more info on this problem. In which class +  namespace are you doing the logging in, and which controller + namespace are you using `var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Guy in russian yii forum answered the question.  (http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=19135&start=20)

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{}
```

I should implement `IdentityInterface` and I've forgotten. 
Now it works well!